# Returning multiple elements based on an array with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to conditionally return different `div`s with this function (first time using React):

```
  currUser().played.forEach(square => {
    if (square === id) {
      console.log(0)
      return (
        <div className="inactive">
        </div>
      );
    };
  });
  return (
    <div className="square">
    </div>
  );
}
```

`0` gets logged a few times, but all outputs are of class `square`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `map` method in order to output an array of elements. Like so:

```js
const Square = () => {

   //...

    return ( 
      <div> 
         currUser().played.map(square => {
           if (square === id) {
           console.log(0)
           return (
              <div className="inactive">
              </div>
             );
           };
           return (
              <div className="square">
              </div>
            );
         })
      </div>
    )

}

export default Square;
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but does this all go within the function?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Square(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: You should return the snippet in my response in `Square` component.

Comment: I edited my  answer. Take a look please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that if you also want to render the div with className="square", if YES then the correct way to do this should be like this:

```
return (
<>
 {currUser().played.filter(square => square === id)
   .map(square => (
      <div className="inactive">
      </div>
    )}
   <div className="square">
   </div>
</>
)
```

First, you have to **filter** out you required elements then chain it with **map** to return and render out the desired elements.

**map** can't be used with **if** condition because **map** should always return something in each iteration. And if you really want to use **if** condition **map**  then you must also return something in **else**

Here curly braces are used to run javascript inside JSX.